# Singly linked list of words

Tags: c, list, linked-list, words

I'm trying to write a function `words`, which produces a singly linked list of words (sequences of characters separated by spaces) from the text passed as a parameter. Words in the resulting list should be the same as in the text .

Unfortunately the program gives error while running, could you explain me what goes wrong and I would also appreciate some hints. Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>

struct node{
    char* word;
    struct node* next;
};

void printList(struct node* list){
    struct node* it = list;
    while(it != NULL){
        printf("%s ", it -> word);
        it = it -> next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void insertLast(struct node* tail, char* neww){
    tail -> next = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    tail = tail -> next;
    tail -> word = neww;
    tail -> next = NULL;
}

struct node* words(char* s){
    char* slowo = strtok(s, " ");
    struct node* head;
    struct node* tail;
    if (sizeof(slowo) == 0)
        return NULL ;
    head = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    head -> word = slowo;
    head -> next = NULL;
    tail = head;
    slowo = strtok(NULL, " ");
    while (slowo != NULL){
        insertLast(tail, slowo);
        tail = tail -> next;
        slowo = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
    return head;
}

int main() {
    printList(words("Some sentance la al olaalal"));
    getch();
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: What exactly doesn't work as you expect? Try to accurately describe a single problem you are having.

Answer (score 1):

If you wan't `insertLast` to set the `tail` in the calling function, you have to pass the pointer by reference (i.e. as a pointer to a pointer.):

```
void insertLast(struct node** tail, char* neww)
```

Use proper dereferencing in `insertLast` for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Your `words()` function modifies its argument (`s`) in-place. You are calling `words()` with a string literal, and modifying a string literal is not allowed. To address this, you could place `s` into heap-allocated memory using `strdup()` or `malloc()+strcpy()`.